# Edge and Ggroup Policy

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, group-policy

I am not a Group Policy expert at all but I need some help for alowwing Edge modification and removal in the 'Application and Services' of Windows 10 because these two buttons are disabled now and I think it can be solved in GP but I do not know where they are, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about **Modify** and **Uninstall** button of Edge in **Apps & features**. Correct me if I misunderstanding anything.

[image]

First, for the **Uninstall** button, we can't enable it. This is designed by Microsoft. Edge is an essential component of Windows operating system and can’t be uninstalled. For detailed information, you can refer to this doc [Why can't I uninstall Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/why-can-t-i-uninstall-microsoft-edge-ee150b3b-7d7a-9984-6d83-eb36683d526d).

Second, for the **Modify** button, from paragraph **Repair Microsoft Edge** of [this doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/what-to-do-if-microsoft-edge-isn-t-working-cc0657a6-acd2-cbbd-1528-c0335c71312a), we can know that:

> If the **Modify** command isn't available, it's likely that your organization installed Microsoft Edge and is managing it for you. For help, contact your system administrator.

We can hardly to precisely direct to certain GP, I suggest that you can consult your domain admin for help.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately the domain admin do not know the solution. I tried to find its parameter in GP for it but no success.